# VS2010 setup project OR condition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I am creating an installer in VS2010, I need to provide OR condition for to possibel registery searches

Will below work...

Example:

```
CONDITION_ONE > '3.0' OR CONDITION_TWO > 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above is a valid conditional statement. For more info check the ['Conditional Statement Syntax'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx) article, especially the logical and comparative operators syntax.